# Unusual Request: Prevent Navigation away from Opportunity

Tags: validation, locking, system-permissions

I've never been asked this before, and from what I've seen there isn't much out there.

### Problem

Users are not completing their tasks on an opportunity before moving to the next sales opportunity or lead that comes in. As a result, customers are orphaned and users forget to return back to their quotes/opportunities and finish them up. This is particularly a problem in busy sales time.

### Request

Our sales team has requested that we prevent navigation away from the opp until they move it into the correct stage. Has anyone ever had this request? I know that I could probably do this with LWC component application, but they are looking for a quick solution with minimal development time.

### My Solutions:

Create a Junction object between Opportunity and User object. The Junction object would be detail side to the user. Then do an aggregate summary on the Custom User Object that looks to see if any of the opps are in a stage they shouldn't be in and redirect them back to the opp that needs to be corrected? Ideally they want something that doesn't even let them leave the opp until it's fixed. Othwerwise, I think the only way this could be accomplished is by LWC build out specifically for an opp layout or a custom VF application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you aware of what the correct stage is at a point in time? What signals an opportunity that needs to be re-looked at? Is this not something validation rules or automated notifications (email alert) could handle?

Comment: The issue is that we the initial stage when a lead is converted to acct/con/opp. They will quote the customer and then disconnect or need to transfer and they forget to wrap up their edits on the opp, and may never return to it. So we need force them to finish their edits in otherwords, prevent them from going anywhere else in the org. But this seems like it's impossible.

Comment: Validation rules, triggers, workflows...are a better and more "standard" platform solution vs "prevent moving away".

Comment: Agreed, but validation rules require user action. We can't really automate the process with a trigger or workflow since the agent needs confirm details and then move the opp themselves before moving it. Essentially they want a popup to occur on the opp if they try to move away from it similar to when you change an API Name on a field.

Comment: What about putting a validation in trigger before update to check whether or not there is any *other* opportunity that meets the criteria and show a message and prevent the users from updating the current opportunity.

Comment: @HengkyIlawan I was thinking something similar to this. However, it would probably create some confusion on their next call. We have a rapid sales environment so that has to be taken into account.

Comment: One thought I had was displaying a different home page if any of the agents had an opp in stage x, it would show only a home page with those opps and tell them to update them before they can begin taking calls that day. Not sure if this is doable on the home page, but i know you can do it with record layouts.

Comment: Would a scheduled job sends emails (or creates tasks that could be viewed in a list view) for users about opportunities they didn't finish be enough of a reminder/nudge? I think the concept of forcing them to finish something won't work if you also what them to move to the next situation if it's a rapid environment.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves that is the second option the devs are leaning towards, but the sales team was hoping for something like a system wide freeze that would prompt them to do something before navigating away. But I think this thread has made it clear that this is not the best option. Instead, maybe a scheduled automation that moves the opps in question + notifying agents that said opp has been moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I discovered that really the best way to get this behavior and what the sales team really was asking for was something akin to a alert() function in SF.

During another project I came across this article on how to build a Modal. I was able to repurpose it in another lightning component to fire based on the data found from an `aura enabled method`.

Here is the article for the Modal. Provides the code and examples on how to use it in other components. If you fire the visibility of the modal (see article's reference to child component), you can freeze the screen and force the user to take an action from the modal and then do whatever updates you need.

Article for Modal:
https://medium.com/@marcoalmodova/a-lwc-confirmation-dialog-5aa486e301e4